# На что влияет ключевое слово "OUTER" в join?

Tags: sql

На что оно влияет в:

- INNER JOIN
- LEFT JOIN:
- RIGHT JOIN:
- FULL JOIN
- CROSS JOIN:

Comment: Ни на что не влияет. Атавизм.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, не влияет нигде? Спасибо, добавь в ответ, - закрою.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OUTER` действительно лишний и может быть опущен, поскольку все соединения `OUTER` являются либо `LEFT`, либо `RIGHT`, и, наоборот, все соединения `LEFT` или `RIGHT` являются `OUTER`. Так что синтаксически это в основном шум. `INNER` тоже лишний.

В целом, если внутри компании решили использовать `OUTER` или `INNER` - придётся использовать, а если нет такого обязательства - можно смело опускать

Answer (score 3):

Раньше писали полностью и до сих пор в описаниях можно найти полные названия. В современном `SQL` пишут короткие версии, экономят слова - и так всё ясно.

| Современная версия | Устаревший стиль |
| --- | --- |
| JOIN | **INNER** JOIN |
| LEFT JOIN | LEFT **OUTER** JOIN |
| RIGHT JOIN | RIGHT **OUTER** JOIN |
| FULL JOIN | FULL **OUTER** JOIN |
| CROSS JOIN | CROSS JOIN |

Comment: inner таки имхо чаще пишут. так что опускают только outer

Comment: @teran Да по факту тоже не пишут, хотя `OUTER`, конечно, писали вообще наверное лет 30 назад, когда я только начинал программировать )

Comment: ради одного выравнивания кода стоит писать. хотя некоторые джойн и в конце предыдущей строки пишут